# Laravel 5.8: The POST method is not supported for this route

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-5.8

I have a form at the Blade like this:

```
@forelse($orders as $order)
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('orders.newprint', ['id'=>$order->id]) }}">
        @csrf
        <tr>
            <td><input class="form-check-input" name="orderCheck[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $order->ord_id }}">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>{{ $order->ord_id }}</td>
        </tr>
        @empty
        <td colspan="7" class="text-center">Nothing to show</td>
@endforelse

        <hr>
        <label>Actions:</label>
        <select class="form-control select2" name="actions" id="actions">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="print_factors">Print Factors</option>
            <option value="print_orders">Print Orders</option>
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-primary float-left">Do</button>              
    </form>
```

And I added this route:

```
Route::post('orders/newprint/{order}','OrdersController@prnpriview')->name('orders.newprint')->middleware('permission:shop-manage');
```

And the method of Controller goes here:

```
public function prnpriview(Request $request, Order $order)
    {
        $checks = $request->input('orderCheck');
        foreach($checks as $check){
            dd($check);
        }
    }
```

But I get this error:

**The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, DELETE.**

I don't know why it shows this because I have specified POST as the route action!

So if you know how to solve this, please let me know...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to check on your route, should have a route is GET method is look similar with your POST method route.

E.g.
Route::post('orders/{example}/{order}','OrdersController@example')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem comes when you have another route that either begins like that one, for example:

```
Route::post('orders/newprint/...
```

or it has the same name

```
->name('orders.newprint')
```

And it's defined after the wanted route.

---

Clarification: In Laravel, when there are same route names defined only the last one will be taken... It works as the array key principle... If you push same key into existing array, that what you set last will be the one in use:

```
$array = [
    'name' => 'route_name'
];

$array['name'] = 'some_different_name';

print_r($array);

// result
Array
(
    [name] => some_different_name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern to match should begin with a forward slash: `'/orders/newprint/{id}'`

While I'd rather call it: `'/orders/{id}/print'` (a matter of taste).

Answer (score 0):

In your action `prnpriview()` in Controller, You put Order object in parameter. And you are sending order id in form
change

```
public function prnpriview(Request $request, Order $order)
```

to

```
public function prnpriview(Request $request, $order_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be issue is in your routing methods.

Try out below things.

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('orders.newprintv1', $order->id) }}">
```

Mention id directly in action route we didn't required a array for single record.

In Route :

```
Route::post('orders/newprint/{order}','OrdersController@prnpriview')->name('orders.newprintv1')->middleware('permission:shop-manage');
```

Change name of the route **orders.newprint** make sure any other route name is not like the same above you write route in route.php check all the routes before this one.

may be check for the resource route ? define any route with orders/newprint.

due to that also making issue.

one more thing for confirm move your existing route without making any changes
make it to first at top of the route.php file like this is your first route.

and then check it will works then other route making conflict with same name.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('orders.newprint', $order->id) }}">
```